# Listview not updating based on dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, updatepanel, dropdownbox

I have an asp dropdown for cities, followed by a dropdown for buildings within the selected city, followed by a listview of rooms in the selected building:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="CityListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CityListDropDown" class="form-control" Width="250" runat="server" DataSourceID="CityListDataSource" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CityListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CityListDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetListOfCities" TypeName="RoomTraq.CityDataServiceReference.CityDataServiceClient"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="BuildingListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="BuildingListDropDown" class="form-control" Width="250" runat="server" DataSourceID="BuildingListDataSource" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BuildingListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="BuildingListDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="BuildingsByCity" TypeName="RoomTraq.BuildingDataServiceReference.BuildingDataServiceClient">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CityListDropDown" Name="CityId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int64" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="RoomListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="RoomListDataSource" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

        ....

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="RoomListDataSource" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="RoomTraq.RoomDataServiceReference.Room" DeleteMethod="DeleteRoom" InsertMethod="AddNewRoom" SelectMethod="RoomsByBuilding" TypeName="RoomTraq.RoomDataServiceReference.RoomDataServiceClient" UpdateMethod="UpdateRoom">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="BuildingListDropDown" Name="BuildingId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int64" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

As you can see, each element gets its data from a datasource that uses the previous element's selected value as the parameter for the query.

In the code behind, I have

```
    protected void CityListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildingListUpdatePanel.Update();
        RoomListUpdatePanel.Update();
    }

    protected void BuildingListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoomListUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

When the page first comes up, everything displays properly with the first city selected and the list of buildings for that city, and the list of rooms for the first building.

When I choose a different building, the list of rooms updates properly.

PROBLEM: When I choose a different city, the list of buildings updates properly, but the list of rooms does not get updated.  Both should update - I have them in update panels so I can do a partial page update of just those panels, and I am telling the panels to update, but the panel does not update itself.  The web service that I have serving out the room data never gets called, until I choose a different building.  But that leaves my page in a bad state when the building list has updated to reflect the new city selection, but the room list is still showing the rooms for a building in the previous city.
Help Please!!